# Error: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'System::String

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, stdstring

I have to compute some string and then print its result in a texbox.
First its definition:

```
             // Mittelwert_Stf
             // 
             this->Mittelwert_Stf->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::Window;
             this->Mittelwert_Stf->Location = System::Drawing::Point(264, 443);
             this->Mittelwert_Stf->Name = L"Mittelwert_Stf";
             this->Mittelwert_Stf->Size = System::Drawing::Size(293, 20);
             this->Mittelwert_Stf->TabIndex = 105;
             this->Mittelwert_Stf->Text = L"-";
```

Then I did some computation and then I would like to concatenate to string using:

```
    std::string stuffe = std::string("Stufe 7") + "wahrscheinlich";
    Mittelwert_Stf->Text = stuffe;
```

but I have the following error:

```
void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'System::String ^'
```

Would anyone please help me how could get ride of?

Comment: Try `Mittelwert_Stf->Text = stuffe.c_str();`

Comment: Thanks but I have an error:

 ` error C2664: 'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'System::String ^' `

Comment: Which character set and encoding is the std::string data in? A specific one or the thread default?

Comment: @TomBlodget The thread default one.